# How to use $index to change class in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-class

I have a list which is limited to 3 items, the first item needs class `blue1`, 2nd needs `blue2`, 3rd `blue3`.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in chartTags" class="blue-tag">
        <div class="tag blue1" ng-class="{blue1: tag == 1 }">{{tag.term}}</div>
    </li>
    <!-- <li><div class="tag blue1">item1</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag blue2">item2</div></li>
    <li><div class="tag blue3">item3</div></li> -->
</ul>
```

Is there a way to write a check like
 `ng-class="{blue1: tag == 1 || blue2: tag == 2 || blue3: tag == 3 }"`

Comment: why don't you try `ng-class="{blue1: tag == 1 , blue2: tag == 2 , blue3: tag == 3 }"`

Comment: @pankajparkar I did, didn't work :(

Comment: check my updated solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could solve this by no need to use track by `$index` as such you don't have duplicates.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="(k, v) in chartTags" class="blue-tag">
     <div ng-class="{blue1: k == 1 , blue2: k == 2 , blue3: k == 3 }">{{v.term}}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work too :) I had to make the first `k == 0`  I like that index syntax, is there a name for it? `(k, v) in chartTags` very clean.

Comment: `(k, v)` are like key value pair of array if its json like `{"a":"1"}` then `a` would be `k` & `v` would be `1` & in array `["1","2","3"]` object `k` would be `0` & `v` would be `1` same for other element

Comment: this will not work in the case of duplication.if you have same(duplicate) item in an array like [1,1,2,3]. in that case it will throw error.

Answer (score 1):

use `$index`.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in chartTags track by $index" class="blue-tag">
        <div class="tag " ng-class="{blue1: $index== 0 ,blue2: $index== 1 ,blue3: $index== 2  }">{{tag.term}}</div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ffPuIyORFIIHMAYCpPyE)

Comment: Hmm just tried that, but got a parse error `Syntax Error: Token '' {1} at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].`

Comment: i have created plunker for you.here it is working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ffPuIyORFIIHMAYCpPyE

Comment: Thanks! Your original code would have worked with just this: `<div class="tag" ng-class="{blue1: $index == 0 , blue2: $index == 1 , blue3: $index == 2 }">{{tag.term}}</div>` needed the first item to be `0` and also `,` not `||`

Answer (score 1):

first you have to track index using `track by` and use `,` to seperate class conditions and not `||`

like this

```
<li ng-repeat="tag in chartTags track by $index" class="blue-tag">
      <div class="tag" ng-class="{blue1: $index == 0, blue2: $index == 1, blue3: $index == 2 }">{{tag}}</div>
</li>
```